# Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called. Vue-Jest-Utils

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have this error when trying to test click event for my Vue JS application with Jest and Utils

I have this error

```
Testing native dom events › calls increment method when button is clicked

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

      34 |     //find the button and trigger click event
      35 |     wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
    > 36 |     expect(change).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |                    ^
      37 | })
      38 |
      39 | })

      at Object.it (tests/unit/form.spec.js:36:20)
```

My vue file is

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="count">
      <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
      <p> {{newCount}} </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="text">
      <button class="test-test" @click="change">Change</button>
      <p id="myText"> {{newText}} </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      count:"",
      newCount: '',
      text:"",
      newText: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.newCount = this.count.split("").reverse().join("")
    },
    change() {
      this.newText = this.text
      document.getElementById("myText").style.fontSize = "xx-large"
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

While my test file is

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';

import Post from '@/components/Form.vue';

describe('Testing native dom events', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(Post);

  it('calls increment method when button is clicked', () => {
      const increment = jest.fn(); // mock function

      // updating method with mock function
      wrapper.setMethods({ increment });

      //find the button and trigger click event
      wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
      expect(increment).toBeCalled();
  })

  it('reverse the string', () => {

    wrapper.setData({ count: 'Yoo' });
    wrapper.setData({ newCount: 'ooY' });
    expect(wrapper.vm.newCount)
        .toEqual('ooY');
  })

  it('calls increment method when button is clicked', () => {
    const change = jest.fn(); // mock function

    // updating method with mock function
    wrapper.setMethods({ change });

    //find the button and trigger click event
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');
    expect(change).toBeCalled();
})

})
```

I try to eleminate one of the button element and sub test and it works, but if i put them together, it seems the seoncd button is not called, do you have some suggestions?

Thank You

Zaid

Comment: read the docs ... find returns the first node ... change is on the second node so test is correct

Comment: Hi, can you explain more? i am still confused about your suggestion? do you mena the docs of Jest or Utils? 

Thank you for the responds

Best

Comment: oh sry: wrapper.find find the first item, thus `wrapper.find("button")` returns `<button @click="increment">Increment</button>` check https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/finding-elements-and-components.html#findall

Comment: Thank you so much, it works so far, really appreciate it.... :), perfecto